# Getting the maximum values of every column and storing those value to an array without pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a text file that looks like this:

```
12345
23451
11221
21219
11223
71231
```

I want to have an array of lengths (`number_of_columns - 1`) that will store the maximum values of each column respectively except for the last column.

So my output array for this above example will look something like: `7 3 4 5`

I don't want to use pandas here. I am unable to understand how to proceed.

Comment: How are you reading the file and accessing the columns?

Comment: if what you given is column then max is 9 how 7 come

Comment: For now I am trying to read that as : 
`import sys
datafile = sys.argv[1];

with open(datafile, 'r') as data:
  plaintext = data.read()`

Comment: @SurajS the max value of first column is 7.

Comment: assign an empty list to hold your maximum for each column, Iterate over each line as a string, split the strings into digits, iterate over the digits casting them each as an int and checking to see if they were higher than what you had in your list of maximums.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

```
with open(datafile) as infile:
    # convert each line to an iterable of ints
    rows = (map(int, line.strip()) for line in infile)
    
    # find the maximum per col, exclude the last one
    *res, _ = (max(col) for col in zip(*rows))
    print(res)
```

**Output**

```
[7, 3, 4, 5]
```

As an alternative:

```
with open(datafile) as infile:
    # convert each line to an iterable of ints exclude the last one
    rows = (map(int, line.strip()[:-1]) for line in infile)

    # find the maximum per col,
    res = [max(col) for col in zip(*rows)]
    print(res)
```

Comment: Ha, you beat me to it.

Comment: Got it. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Dani Mesejo in some cases I can have a file where the value of every row can be separated by comma, `(for an example the first row of above example will look like : 1,2,3,4,5)` then how to change this code there?

Answer (score 0):

```py
[max(lst) for lst in zip(*[map(int,line) for line in data.split() if line])][:-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this. Here's just one of them:

```
with open('foo.txt') as infile:
    a = []
    for line in infile:
        for i, d in enumerate(line[:-2]):
            if len(a) < i+1:
                a.append([])
            a[i].append(int(d))
    print(*map(max,a))
```